# add global callback to $.ajaxSetup

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, callback

I am use `$.ajaxSetup` to use a global authorization method, and global error handling in my site. I would like to pass a callback function into the global error method so I can call the function whenever I need to in the global error handler. Here is my `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
       global: false,
       // type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            //The string needs to be turned into 'this.pasToken'
            //if not us, don't include
            if(app.cookieAuth)
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", _this.pasToken);
        },
        statusCode: {
            401: function(){
                //Redirect to the login window if the user is unauthorized
                window.location.href = app.loginUrl;
            },
            //This is where I need help
            403: function(error, callback){
                //Show an error message if permission isn't granted
                callback(error);
                alert(JSON.parse(error.responseText)['Message']);
            }
        }
     });
```

Note the `403:` status code. I am trying to pass in a callback function, but I don't know how to do it from the individual `ajax` calls. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution; define your own property for ajax options.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        403: function(error, callback){
            this.callback403(error);
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
    callback403: function () {}
});
```

Note, if you change the `context` option of the ajax request, this may not work.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
       404: function() {
     alert("page not found");
    }
   }
   });
```